# Dervation of the first-order Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, perturbation-theory, klein-gordon-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

How to derive the first-order perturbed Klein-Gordon equation:

$$ \square \phi=\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}
\partial_{\mu}\left(\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\nu} \right) \right]\phi=0$$

For a first-order perturbed metric:

$$ g_{00} = -a^2 ( 1+ 2 \Phi), ~~~ g_{0i} = 0 , ~~~~ g_{ij} = a^2 (1-2 \Psi).
 $$

Here is my trial:

First : $ \sqrt{-g}= \sqrt{a^2 (1 +2 \Phi)  (1 -2 \Psi)^3 }$

Also the scalar field: $\phi$ is perturbed :  $\phi(x,t) \to \phi_0(t) + \phi_1(x,t) $. And both $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are functions of (x,t).

The KG equation becomes:

$$\partial_0  \sqrt{-g} g^{00} \partial_0 \phi + \partial_i  \sqrt{-g} g^{ij} \partial_j \phi=0 
$$

Perturbe $g^{\mu\nu}$ and $\phi$, the equation becomes:

$$\partial_0  \sqrt{-g} (g^{00}+ \delta^{(1)} g^{00} ) \partial_0 (\phi_0 + \phi_1 ) + \partial_i  \sqrt{-g}  (g^{ij}+ \delta^{(1)} g^{ij} )   \partial_j (\phi_0 + \phi_1 )  =0 
$$

Yields:

$$
\partial_0  \sqrt{-g} (-a^{-2} + -a^{-2}/2 \Phi^{-1} ) \partial_0 (\phi_0 + \phi_1 ) + \partial_i  \sqrt{-g}  (a^{-2} - a^{-2}/2 \Psi^{-1})   \partial_j (\phi_0 + \phi_1 )  =0 
$$

Now I’m confuced how to substite by $\sqrt{-g}$ and get only the first order terms .

So any help to deal with the terms under the square root and complete the derivation.

I should get a result similar to equation (3.4) [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1787).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, one has
$$
\sqrt{-g}=\sqrt{a^8(1-2\Phi)(1-2\Psi)^3}\approx a^4\left(1-\Phi-3\Psi\right).
$$