# Partial derivative operator

Tags: differentiation, calculus

It's mentioned in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1787) that if $\partial^i \partial^j$ applied on an equation like:

$$ 
x \delta_{ij} + (\nabla^2 \delta_{ij}- \partial_i \partial_j) y =0 
$$

It yields a couple of equations:

$$
\nabla^2 y=0, 
$$
and,

$$
x=0
$$

This means:

$ \partial^i \partial^j \delta_{ij} =1  ~~~  \star$

And

$
\partial^i \partial^j \partial_i \partial_j = 0  ~~~  \star
$

Any explanation for that?

Because I think: $ \partial^i \partial^j \delta_{ij} = \partial^i \partial_i = \nabla^2 $

And even if the $\star$ relations are true why the equation splits into a couple of equations.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where exactly in the paper is it used? (page and Eqn. number please...)

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/808045/2451

Comment: Hi @JosBergervoet. In the paper, similar to the equation that I have mentioned equ. (3.11), and similar to the star $\star$ relations, equ. (3.13) and (3.14).

Comment: @JosBergervoet. As mentioned in the paper in the paragraph before equ. (3.13) that $\partial^i \partial^j$ is transverse to $\nabla^2 \delta_{ij} - \partial_i \partial_j $, so I would like to know what that means